# Explicit formula for $a_0=1$, $a_{n+1}=a_n^2+1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Is there an explicit formula in elementary function for the sequence $a_n$ where $a_0=1$, $a_{n+1}=a_n^2+1$? How does one prove or disprove such claims?

Edit: I think my question may be formulated in the following way: Is there an elementary function $f$ which satisfies $f(0)=1$ and $f(n+1)=f(n)^2+1$?

Comment: [A003095](http://oeis.org/A003095) The page does not give an explicit formula but there are some links to articles and a list of topics where this sequence arises.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut thanks for the reference!

Comment: This may also be relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1918972/finding-an-explicit-formula-for-a-n-defined-recursively-by-a-n1-a-n26

Comment: @DavidK thanks!

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2525139/closed-form-for-the-given-recurrence-relation

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks. But how do one prove that such a sequence does not have an closed form expression?

Comment: @Jiu: by trying all possible expressions and showing that they don't match ?

Comment: @Jiu Since "closed form" is not precisely defined, one can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [A. V. Aho and N. J. A. Sloane, Some doubly exponential sequences, Fib. Quart., 11 (1973), 429-437](http://neilsloane.com/doc/doubly.html), 
$$ a(n+1) = \text{round}(b^{2^n})$$
where
$b$ is a certain real number, approximately  $2.25851845058946539883779624006373187243427469718511465966\ldots$

Comment: With a simple calculator, $2.2585184505894653988377962400637$, estimated from $a_7$.

Comment: Based on formula from your link , $b = \exp\left[\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}\log\left(1 + \frac{1}{a_k^2}\right)\right]$

Answer (score 1):

As the sequence is very quickly growing, past a certain term, let $a_m$, the $+1$ becomes really tiny and the iterates are well approximated by

$$x_n=(x^m)^{2^{n-m}}.$$

An interesting question is if it holds that

$$x_n\sim c^{2^n}$$ where $c$ would be

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[2^n]x_n.$$